# Transform list of Either into list of left and list of right

Tags: java, either, vavr

Vavr's Either seems to solve one of my problems were some method does a lot of checks and returns either CalculationError or CalculationResult.

```java
Either<CalculationError, CalculationResult> calculate (CalculationData calculationData) {
// either returns Either.left(new CalculationError()) or Either.right(new CalculationResult())

}
```

I have a wrapper which stores both errors and results

```
class Calculation {
 List<CalculationResult> calculationResults;
 List<CalculationError> calculationErrors;
}
```

Is there any neat solution to transform stream from `Collection<CalculationData> data` to `Calculation`?

Comment: @andyczerwonka Then look again, perhaps. An `Either<CE, CR>` can store either precisely 1 CE, or precisely 1 CR. In contrast, a Calculation can store for exmaple 18 CEs and 14 CRs. It's more powerful.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question. I need a class which stores list of successful and unsuccessful calculations.

Comment: My mistake, I saw `Either` and I assumed Scala. I removed my answer as it is not helpful.

Comment: Heh, yeah vavr can throw you for a loop on that one @andy

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using a custom collector. With a bit of pseudo code representing the `Either`:

```
Collector<Either<CalculationError, CalculationResult>, ?, Calculation> collector = Collector.of(
        Calculation::new,
        (calc, either) -> {
            if (either has error) {
                calc.calculationErrors.add(either.error);
            } else {
                calc.calculationResults.add(either.result);
            }
        },
        (calc1, calc2) -> {
            calc1.calculationErrors.addAll(calc2.calculationErrors);
            calc1.calculationResults.addAll(calc2.calculationResults);
            return calc1;
        }
);

Calculation calc = data.stream()
        .map(this::calculate)
        .collect(collector);
```

Note that `Calculation` should initialize its two lists (in the declaration or a new constructor).

Comment: It's nice despite the fact that `Calculation` class is mutable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're using vavr, so 'neat' is right out. Tends to happen when you use tools that are hostile to the idiomatic form of the language. But, then again, 'neat' is a nebulous term with no clear defined meaning, so, I guess, whatever *you* think is 'neat', is therefore 'neat'. Neat, huh?

Either itself has the `sequence` method - but both of them work the way Either is supposed to work: They are left-biased in the sense that any Lefts present is treated as erroneous conditions, and that means all the Right values are discarded if even one of your Eithers is a Left. Thus, you cannot use either of the `sequence` methods to let Either itself bake you a list of the Right values. Even `sequenceRight` won't do this for you (it stops on the first Left in the list and returns that instead). The filter stuff similarly doesn't work like that - Either very much isn't really an Either in the sense of what that word means if you open a dictionary: It does **not** mean: A homogenous mix of 2 types. It's solely a non-java-like take on exception management: Right contains the 'answer', left contains the 'error' (you're using it correctly), but as a consequence there's nothing in the Either API to help with this task - which in effect involves 'please filter out the errors and then do something' ("Silently ignore errors" is rarely the right move. It *is* what is needed here, but it makes sense that the Either API isn't going to hand you a footgun. Even if you need it here).

Thus, we just write it plain jane java:

```java
var calculation = new Calculation();
for (var e : mix) {
  if (e.isLeft()) calculation.calculationErrors.add(e.getLeft());
  if (e.isRight()) calculation.calculationResult.add(e.getRight());
}
```

(This presumes your Calculation constructor at least initializes those lists to empty mutables).

NB: Rob Spoor's answer also assumes this and is much, much longer. Sometimes the functional way is the silly, slow, unwieldy, hard to read, way.

NB2: `Either.sequence(mix).orElseRun(s -> calculation.errors = s.asJava());` is a rather 'neat' way (perhaps - it's in the eye of the beholder) of setting up the `errors` field of your Calculation class. No joy for such a 'neat' trick to fill the 'results' part of it all, however. That's what the bulk of my answer is trying to explain: There is no nice API for that in Either, and it's probably by design, as that involves intentionally ignoring the errors in the list of Eithers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using VAVr, you may consider using `Traversable` instead of `Collection`. This will give you the method `partition`, which can be used to classify your list of `Either`s into two groups like so:

```java
Traversable<Either<CalculationError, CalculationResult>> calculations = ...;
var partitionedCalcs = calculations.partition(Either::isRight);
var results = partitionedCalcs._1.map(Either::getRight);
var errors = partitionedCalcs._2.map(Either::getLeft);
Calculation calcs = new Calculation(results, errors);
```

If you don't want to change your existing use of `Collection` to use a `Traversable`, then you can easily convert between them by using, for example, `List.ofAll(Iterator)` and `Value.toJavaCollection(Function)`.